# How is it possible to reduce the size of Html file generated from Folium map in Python?

Tags: html, folium

I'm using folium.GeoJson to plot polygons on a map. I have one dataset with different fields/attributes; I'm using the same data for each folium.GeoJson layer but with various fields to display different attributes and add them in layer control. I guess this makes the final Html file big in size.

One solution I found to reduce the Html file is to minify it, but the slimmer package isn't available in anaconda.

Do you have any suggestions for this case?

Answer (score 0):

Found a way: to simplify spatial data that significantly reduces data size.

In my case, I was using shapefile as the spatial data, particularly polygons, that is, the collection of points (vertices) and highly affected the data size. I just used the simplification tool that removes extraneous vertices but preserves essential shape. I used the Simplify Polygon tool in ArcMap, but the same is possible in python with the `geopandas.GeoSeries.simplify` function and in R with the 'sf' library.

Comment: Can you add the solution on how you simplified?

Comment: In my case, I was using shapefile as the spatial data, particularly polygons, that is, the collection of points (vertices) and highly affected the data size. I just used the simplification tool that removes extraneous vertices but preserves essential shape. I used the Simplify Polygon tool in ArcMap, but the same is possible in python with the 'geopandas.GeoSeries.simplify' function and in R with the 'sf' library.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the size of the HTML file dramatically by using [mapshaper](https://mapshaper.org/) to reduce the size of the geojson file.

Drop your file or search and import. I check the box "detect line intersections" and upload:

[image: mapshaper-import]

Choose your method of simplifying the coordinates (I use Douglas-Peucker method, and prevent shape removal):

[image: simplification-with-mapshaper]

Then set the simplification (you can play with the settings to get the desired result, I found 3% worked well)

[image: mapshaper-setting]

Then export the file (it exports as a .json file so remember to change to .geojson:

[image: mapshaper-export]

This reduced the file from 17.6MB to 614KB and the outputted HTML file from 222MB to 7.58MB